# Changing size of different characters in text view, Android

Tags: textview, android

I want to create a Text view in which I want some characters to be of 40pt size and some characters to be of 20pt.

I tried using Html.fromhtml() but can't find any tag for changing size as such..

pleas help if this Is possible.

Comment: take different textviews and append them..

Comment: can u give any sort of example? hw u want to show.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder("Different");
spanTxt.append(" android.");
//make the textsize 2 times.
spanTxt.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), spanTxt.length() - " android".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use html for this.

for eg. *A* **A** *A*

```
String abc="<font color=BLUE><i>A</i></font>";
abc=abc+"<b>A</b><i>A</i>";
textView.setText(Html.formHtml(abc));
```

You can set Any size of the text using the font tag and also set it's color..

This is the easiest way to do this;

Comment: This should work, but in the case of changing size this doesn't do the job.